# How to add both text and img to a button and center them vertically

Tags: html, css

I am writing a button with the following structure, but I have difficulty centering the text (this button) and the img vertically. I tried to add padding to img, but I found out the text and img is still aligned at the top.

```
<button>
    This button
    <img src="icon.svg" alt="Info Icon" height="15" width="15" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add flex css.

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button>
    This button
    <img src="icon.svg" alt="Info Icon" height="15" width="15" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button>
    This button
    <img src="icon.svg" alt="Info Icon" height="15" width="15" />
</button>
```

I will explain to you the changes I have done and what each of them means for your future reference and understanding.

The `display: block` is basically similar to `flex` and it is usually used in cases where you want to display a certain text/image as a block or paragraphs or headers. It tolerates no HTML elements next to it, and I feel like this would be necessary considering your scenario where you only want the picture next to the button and no other HTML element. Then I just justified the content, basically everything to the center.

Hope this helps, and let me know if there is anything missing or needs to be added.